# A better architecture than passing callback functions to children Widgets

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm building my first Flutter app, in which I need to refresh a list of data, and every component has some modifiers.
This is the basic architecture.

[image]

A **big** list of data (about 5000 rows) is periodically refreshed from an API inside a `RefresherWidget` (which is a `StatefulWidget` that holds the list), and then passed along to the children.
Every `RowWidget` has a `Switch` (and `Dialogs` too) that modifies the data it represents.

Currently, **the methods to modify the list** are in the `RefresherWidget`, so I'm passing them as callback functions inside **every** children until reaching the `onChanged` callback of the `Switch`.

But I don't think it's a very clean solution, and I don't know how to implement a better one: I've tried thinking about passing these methods inside an `InheritedWidget` that stays between `RefresherWidget` and `ListViewWidget`, and referencing them using the `of` function, but I don't know about the perfomance hit I would get if the `InheritedWidget` gets rebuild.

Also, Streams and BLoCs seem very complicated for what I need to do.

How do you guys usually approach a problem like this?

Comment: you can use [MobX](https://mobx.pub/) . It includes less tedious boilerplate code as most of the code is auto-generated for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a situation for `InheritedWidget` or `BuildContext` in general.

> I've tried [...] InheritedWidget [...] but I don't know about the perfomance hit I would get if the InheritedWidget gets rebuild.

You don't have to fear anything. `InheritedWidget` is built for this exact purpose.

Obtaining the `InheritedWidget` is very performant (O(1)). And only widgets that depends on the value gets rebuilt – which is optimal too.

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up using it and my code is much better organized. Perfomance seems the same, maybe even better...